# execute sql query taking inputs from a text file

Tags: sql-server, file, text, input

I have a text file containing a very large list of md5s as:

```
0x7434BEAC929E7EB32E6363E2F75F2835
0x7D8C86BA729178F34F999D6E585E055F
0x2578C524E6A222331F6563595D2A6C85
0xA59B09B20E78B45B095946ADEF1B23A7
0x12CC68765B1A3CE7ED1244C2FEAD1805
```

I want to take one md5 at a time from this file and execute the query, something like:

```
select * from table1 where col1 like ('%some_value%') 
AND col2 =('0xA59B09B20E78B45B095946ADEF1B23A7','0x12CC68765B1A3CE7ED1244C2FEAD1805',...)
```

The part `col2='0xA59B09B20E78B45B095946ADEF1B23A7','0x12CC68765B1A3CE7ED1244C2FEAD1805',...)` should be taken as input from the text file for all the values in it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try a `BULK INSERT`  to a table (even a temp table or table variable), and then do your `Select` against that like so:

```
Select * from table1
where col2 in (select md5 from @TableVar)
```

You can read up on [Bulk Insert here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms188365.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the reply... but actually I do not want to create temp tables... Can we read from text files in sql servers?

Comment: You can probably insert to your actual table (`table1` in your code) using a bulk insert, avoiding the temp table entirely. As far as I know, there are a few ways of reading from text files, but `BULK INSERT` is probably the easiest.